# dc.js heatmap how to rotate text ?

Tags: css, d3.js, css-selectors, dc.js

how to select and rotate the texts of the x axis only ! 
In this Example : 
http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/heat.html

So select from 1 to 20 and rotate them !

I tried this way :

```
 chart
 .selectAll("g.cols.axis > text")  
 .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
 .attr("transform", function () {
    return "rotate(-20)"
   })
 .style("fill", "blue");
```

but it seems that I'am selecting the whole X-axis and not every text separatly .
The fill style works fine but the transformation does not work properly and the  axe is entirely rotated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must rotate each text element on X Axis around its own center. To do that you must specified the rotation angle AND the center of rotation

```
rotate(angle centerX centerY)
```

With that on mind, you can do:

```
  chart.selectAll('g.cols.axis > text')
            .attr('transform', function (d) {
                var coord = this.getBBox();
                var x = coord.x + (coord.width/2),
                    y = coord.y + (coord.height/2);
                return "rotate(-20 "+x+" "+y+")"
                });
```

Remember do it after call to `chart.render();` or your selection will be empty

If you want understand why this, take a look at: https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-transformations/

[Here the working code](https://plnkr.co/edit/VrWGaCCM5GuBlMFMF7eJ?p=preview)

Comment: Best place to do this is `.on('pretransition', function(chart) { ... })`, at least if you're using the 2.0 betas. This fires after any render or redraw. (Renderlet in earlier versions, but that's after transitions so there is a jump.)

Comment: Thank you for you both ! It works ! 
I have one more question , what if in th X axis I have multiple strings with different length ! how to let those strings to be drawn starting from each first char ?  If I use .attr('dy', '+50') the result wont be bad but not the desired ! because of the different length of each String ... 
 chart.selectAll("g.cols.axis text")
.attr('dy', '+50')
.attr("transform", function () {
var coord = this.getBBox();
 var x = coord.x + (coord.width / 2),
y = coord.y + (coord.height / 2);
 return "rotate(90 " + x + " " + y + ")"
})
.style("fill", "blue");

Comment: Text label can be align using ' text-anchor' property. 'start' 'middle' 'end'. Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
.cols.axis text{
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotateX(-20deg);
}
```

I'm not sure if that's the axis you wanna rotate on since it just moves them up over the chart - but for any axis you can just use rotateX/Y/Z!

Comment: Oh I see what you mean...hmmm.

Comment: it seems that the problem is with the css selector .selectAll("g.cols.axis > text")

Comment: I think it's actually that the transform origin seems to be stuck on the left of the entire axis even if you set it for each element

Comment: It looks like you need to individually assign the transform origin of each element in pixels, fun stuff. Should be able to use a loop to increment through and adjust based on the font size and coordinates.